# Why $\lim_{h\to0}(2+h^2)$ is equal to 2 but not one?

Tags: calculus

Excerpt from chapter on [Differentiation](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~chris/concepts%20of%20calculus/CHAP03%20Differentiation.pdf)(P.3) tells that

> To say that $\lim_{h\to0}(2+h^2)$ doesn’t quite mean that $(2+h^2)$ gets closer and closer to $2$ as $h$ gets closer to $0$.After all $(2+h^2)$ gets closer and closer to 1 as h gets closer and closer to 0, but $\lim_{h\to0}(2+h^2)=2$,not 1.

Why does the article says that "$\lim_{h\to0}(2+h^2)$  doesn’t quite mean that $(2+h^2)$ gets closer and closer to $2$ as $h$ gets closer to $0$"?

Comment: I think that means that 2 is not the unique number $2+h^2$ get closer to when $h$ goes to $0$.

Comment: Why do you think it will be equal to 1?

Comment: This remark shows that it's not a good idea to think about a limit $L$ as being the (only?!) number your expression $f(h)$ gets "_closer and closer_" to, since that's the case for infinitely many numbers. It is however the only number where the expression $f(h)$ gets "_arbitrarily close_" to, i.e. "**as close as you want**".

Comment: @StackTD:I couldn't get this sentence you mentioned "since that's the case for infinitely many numbers".

Comment: *that* was badly written!  It means that as h gets closer to 0.  2+h^2 gets closer to *ALL* the numbers less than 2.  It gets closer to 1, it gets closer to zero.  It gets closer to -27, etc.  So the point is that isn't the Def of limit. It doesn't just get closer to the limit; the distance from the limit gets closer to 0.  That was *TERRIBLY* written.  An example of a bizarre error should never be *harder* to understand than the correct way of doing things.

Comment: @fleablood:Okay.Still can't get why 2+h^2 gets closer to all the numbers less than 2.As my view goes I can't get how to make the value of (2+h^2) smaller when you aren't doing any subtraction or division.

Comment: Nothing is actually getting closer to anything. We are considering  an infinite set of values that $h$ may take. The sentence  $\lim_{h\to 0}(2+h^2)=2$ means $\forall e>0\;\exists d>0\; \forall h\; (|h|<d\implies |(2+h^2)-2|<e).$ And no more.

Answer (score 5):

As $h\to0$, the value of $2+h^2$ decreases, and so, gets closer to $1$. However, that does not mean that
$$
\lim_{h\to0^+}\left(2+h^2\right)=1\tag{1}
$$
For $\lim\limits_{h\to0^+}\left(2+h^2\right)=L$, we need that no matter how small we make $\varepsilon\gt0$, we can find a $\delta\gt0$ so that if $|h|\le\delta$, then $\left|\left(2+h^2\right)-L\right|\le\varepsilon$. This can be done with $L=2$, but not with $L=1$.

Therefore, setting $\delta=\sqrt{\varepsilon}$, we get
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\left(2+h^2\right)=2\tag{2}
$$

Comment: :Could you tell why the value of $(2+h^2)$ decreases as $h\to0^+$?

Comment: As $h\to0$, $h^2$ decreases to $0$.  That is, the smaller that $|h|$ is, the smaller $2+h^2$ is. As $2+h^2$ decreases, it gets closer to $1$.  It is still bounded away from $1$ by a distance of $1$, but it keeps getting closer to $1$.

Comment: :Could you tell how could $(2+h^2)$ decrease because I can't see any subtraction or division taking place.

Comment: As $h$ gets closer to $0$, $h^2$ decreases to $0$. I am not sure where the difficulty is. Say $h=\frac{(-1)^n}n$, then $2+h^2=2+\frac1{n^2}$ which decreases to $2$ as $h$ gets closer to $0$. Since $2+h^2$ decreases to $2$, it gets closer to $1$ (but never closer than $1$ away).

Comment: :Oh I see.Do you mean to say that $h^2$ decreases to $0$?Even if $h^2$ decreases to $0$ how could we decrease '2' in the expression $(2+h^2)$ to make it $1$?

Comment: @justin: it gets closer to $1$, but never comes close to $1$.  That is the point.  If I travel from San Francisco to Los Angeles, I would get closer to San Diego, but I wouldn't get any closer than $100$ miles from San Diego; however, I would get closer to San Diego as I traveled to Los Angeles. I would get closer to San Diego, even if my limit was Los Angeles.

Comment: :That's a good way of explaining ideas.I haven't gone to these places.Could you give the distance between each place?

Comment: It's horribly written.  It assumes a student will make an error that no student ever has.  Instead of 1, take -27.  -27 < 2+ h^2 < 2+ (h+)^2.  So 2 + h^2, "gets closer" to -27.  But it doesn't get arbitrarily close.  It is always at least 29 away.  So "get closer" to isn't a good definition for limit.  That's all it's saying.

Comment: @fleablood: I don't see this question as assuming a student will make any mistake. I see it as pointing out the difference between "getting closer to" and "limiting to".

Comment: @justin: [Map of California](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tehr5.png). The exact distances are not important.

Comment: @fleablood:I appreciate that and I that's the same idea robjohn was trying to tell but since I couldn't get the map of California it took some time to understand.

Comment: @fleablood:Even thought that solved the confusion of "get closer" still can't get how $(2+h^2)$ get closer to 1.It's obvious that '2' is closer to '1' and we could also say that 1.0000009 is far closer to '1' than '2'.Why couldn't they have said '2' is closer to '3'.Isn't it closer?

Comment: @robjohn:Why couldn't they have said '2' is closer to '3'.Isn't it closer?

Comment: @justin: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to say. '2' is closer to '3' that what?  The point of the example is to show that "getting closer to" is not the same as "getting close to".

Comment: @robjohn:Oh sorry I meant to say why they are focusing on '1'.Why couldn't they pick another number than 1?

Comment: They are not focusing on $1$. Any number less than $2$ would have worked as well. I could also have used Mexico City or Rio de Janeiro in my example, but I chose San Diego.

Comment: @justin: However, with respect to $3$, as $h\to0$, $2+h^2$ does not get closer to $3$, but it does get closer to $1$, $0$, $-1$, etc.

Comment: @robjohn:Shouldn't they have said $h\to-1$.Isn't that more appropriate?

Comment: @justin: more appropriate for what? The example works fine for $h\to0$. I guess they could have used $\lim\limits_{h\to-1}2+h^2=3$, but again, their example works just fine.

Comment: Again, this is terribly written because  the reader will spend far too much time trying to "get it" when the thing they are trying to get is *an error*.  $2 + h^2$ "gets closer" to .... oh let's say 1.  because $2 + .1^2 > 2+ .01^2 > 2+.001^2 > 2+.0001^2 > .... > 2 > 1.  The *only* point of this statement is to point out "closer to" is NOT a good definition of limit.  If you are "getting closer" to something it doesn't mean that is you r limit.  If I drive from San Francisco to New York I am getting closer to London.  But london isn't my limit.

Comment: Maybe you should have chosen London.  As you move closer and closer to the atlantic ocean you get closer and closer to London but London *isn't* your destination.  "Getting closer to" isn't the definition of limit.  Getting "arbitrarily close to" is.

Comment: @robjohn  The reason I think it is badly written is that in explaining the difference between "getting closer to" and "limmiting to" it's not being aware that a readers misconception is thinking "getting closer" includes "limiting to".  Instead it assumes the readers misconception is in thinking "limiting to" is only "getting closer.  The reader's issue is the exact opposite; it doesn't occur to them "getting closer" *wouldn't* be the same as "limiting to".  So they think  "But it *isn't* getting closer to 1!!!"  Hence poor Justin's confusion.

Comment: "getting closer"  =  "Hey, ! this month Earth is getting closer to Jupiter".  "limiting to"  = "Watch out!  You're going to *hit* that guy.... *CRASH*"

Answer (score 2):

This excerpt is a candidate for one of the worst written things I have ever read.

Pre-amble: In the fifties and early sixties there was a radio comedy duo called Bob and Ray and they once did a comedy skit "Wally the Word Man and Mr. Wise Old Owl on Prodigy Street" which was a satire of a children's educational television show.  In it Wally the Word mad tries to teach the children the letters of the alphabet and when he gets to "I" Mr. Wise Old Owl point "notice, children, the the letter I looks like the number 1, 1 is first number when we count."  "Thank you Mr. Wise Old Owl but we are teaching the children to read and although this coincidentally might look a little like the number one it is the letter I and something else entirely".  When they get to the letter "O" Mr. Wise Old Owls "And, see children, the O looks like the number 0, zero actually the first number but when we count we start with the number 1 even though it is the second number."  "Mr.  Wise Old Owl, I *really* wish you wouldn't do this.  I'm afraid it confuses the children." "But Wally the Word Man, I'm just trying to point this out so the children won't make the mistake." Then Wally the Word Man tries to teach them to read the word "ATTENTION" and Mr. Wise Old Owl says "And see children, the I and O look like the number 10 and the word attention says 'ten' in the middle but the the 10 in attention is in a different place than the I and the O". "Okay, that's it!  You and me, Mr. Wise Old Owl, out inn the alley! ..."

I almost feel this excerpt is very similar.  It's trying to point out to the reader what a limit is NOT by pointing out that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} 2 + h^2 \ne 1$  ("Don't make that mistake, children!  The limit is not really 1!") which leaves the readers scratching their heads muttering "why the F@!# would I think the limit is *$*1*$*?!?!?!"  So they they go to stack exchange and go through huge and confusing discussions how if you take certain misconceptions by a faulty argument one can say "2 + h^2" can "get closer to 1" to which the readers say "I still don't get it and what is so special about the number 1?" and bang their heads against the wall because they can not understand a subtelty of a badly explained !*MISTAKE*!.

You know something is wrong when that happens.

So  this is how Uncle Fleablood would explain it:

Most students have an idea what claiming $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} 2 + h^2 =2$ means;  The values of the expression approach and hone in toward the value 2.  However coming up with a formal definition for "honing in" might be more tricky.  A novice might incorrectly say "the sequence will eventually get to 2" but this isn't true because the sequence itself may be infinite will never actually have any final value or 2.  Many mathematicians, even professionals and professors, might say "the values of the sequence get closer to 2".  This is true but this alone, as expressed, is an imprecise and insufficient to be the definition of a sequence.  After all, $2 + h^2$ is a decreasing sequence and it not only "gets closer" to 2;  it "gets closer" to *every* number that's 2 or lower!  (The sequence gets closer to, say, -27 but it always stays more than 29 away--  but it gets closer and closer to being 29 away!)  "Getting closer" doesn't mean "getting arbitrarily close".  A precise definition of limit must not only express the idea of the sequence getting "closer" to a value, but also getting *arbitrarily* close to the value.

And that is *ALL* the author meant when s/he said $2 + h^2$ gets closer to 1.  It does!  It also gets closer to $0$, to $-1,$ to $-6,532*\sqrt{\pi}$ etc.

---

So the upshot is, the definition of limit will include not just that the sequence gets close to the value, but for any positive distance, we can find a point in the sequence where all the terms are closer to the value *than the arbitrary positive distance*.

$2 + h^2$ does get closer to 1, but $|(1) - (2 + h^2)| = 1 + h^2 > 1$.  *Always*.  so the sequence never gets closer than 1 to 1.

$2 + h^2$ gets closer to 2, *AND* $|(2) - (2 + h^2)| = h^2$ and although $h^2 > 0$ always but for *any* positive $\epsilon > 0$ there is *always* a point where $h^2 < \epsilon$ so $2 + h^2$ gets *arbitrarily* close to 2.  But it *doesn't* get arbitrarily close to 1.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to write this, and thanks for Bob and Ray.

Comment: @fleablood:That's a great answer.Do you mean to say that we can take any value for $h$?If that's true we can make $2+h^2$ as a decreasing function by substituting values for $h$ as $0,-1,-2$ or any number below $0$.Am I wrong?

Comment: YOu are way overthinking this. but, no, if h < 0 then $h^2 > 0$ and as h gets further from 0 (in either direction) $h^2$ gets further from 0 in either direction.

Comment: @fleablood:Could you tell why $2+h^2$ gets _arbitrarily_ close to $2$?I couldn't get how $2+h^2$ becomes $2$ even if we substitute negative or positive vaues for $h$.

Comment: It never equals 2 if h never equals 0.  But we can get it "as close to 2 as we like".  If we want to get within 1/1,000,000, we can by take h $\le$ 1,000.  If we want to get within 1-googolth, we can by taking h to be the square root of 1-googolth.  "as close to as we like" is not very rigorous and well defined mathematically, but the term "arbitrarily close" does have a rigorous and well defined mathematical definition. .... to be continued...

Comment: $2+h^2$ can be "arbitrarily close" to 2  =  for *any* real $\epsilon > 0$ we can find a value of h (or whatever variable) such that the difference between $2+h^2$ (or whatever expression) and 2 (or whatever) is less than $\epsilon$.  i.e. $|(2 + h^2) - 2| < 0$.  So for instance:  If $\epsilon > 0$, I can set $h$ to be such that $0 < |h| < \sqrt{\epsilon}$.  Then $(2 + h^2) - 2 = h^2 < \epsilon$.  As $\epsilon$ was arbitrarily small, we can conclude $2 + h^2$ gets arbitrarily close to 2.  Obviously $2+h^2$ can not get arbitrarily close to 1.  ... to be continued ...

Comment: $|(2+h^2) - 1| = 1 + h^2 > 1$.  So *whatever* $h$ we choose we will *never* get $|(2 + h^2)  - 1| < 1$.  So $2 + h^2$ is *not* arbitrarily close to 1.  Indeed, if $m \ne 2$ then $k = |2 - m| > 0$ and $|(2 + h^2) - m| = k + h^2 > k$ and we *never* get $|2 + h^2 - m| < k$ so $2+h^2$ is *not* arbitrarily close to $m$.  So $2 + h^2$ is arbitrarily close to 2 but it is not arbitrarily close to any other value.  "Arbitrarily close" is the key to defining "limit".  .... to be continued...

Comment: we can't define $\lim f(h) = f(h)$ for two reasons.  1) f(h) might not be defined, and 2) if f isn't continuous the function can jump about like a flea and not approach f(h) at all.  We can't define $\lim f(h)\rightarrow c$ as "f(h) gets closer to c as h gets closer to c" because that isn't specific enough.  So we need the concept of "arbitrarily close".  That is the best way to define "approach".  We use it also to define tricky concepts such as "continuous" as well.

Comment: @fleablood:To be honest I'm very weak in maths.Eventhough I appreciate the effort to write all these comments I couldn't get the meaning of any comment.It's my fault.I really couldn't get the [epsion-delata definition of limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit).I think that's why I could't understand these comments.Could you help me.

Comment: @fleablood:Does the epsilon-delta definition of limit means that for every $c$ where $c\pm\delta$ we get an _respectively_ $L\pm\epsilon$?

Comment: Sort of but you have it backwards.  $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} f (x) = L $ means as x gets really really close to $x_0$ then f (x) gets really really close to L.  But how do we say that formally?       We want to prove we can get f (x) really close L.  How close? as close as $\epsilon > 0$.  We want to prove we can get f (x) as close as $\epsilon$ to L.  $\epsilon$ is as small as we want, and we want to prove that we can get that close.  That means $|f (x)-L|<\epsilon $.  That's what we want to show we can do.

Comment: That's what we want to be able to show.  To show that that is possible we must prove the there is, specific to *that* distance $\epsilon $ that there is another distance $\delta $.  If we get x and $x_0$ closer than $\delta $ then that forces f (x) and L to be closer than $\epsilon $.  If we choose a really really tiny epsilon, than we can show we can find a really tiny delta so that x closer than delta to x_0 means f (x) is closer than L than epsilon.

Comment: @fleablood:Yeah that's very right.Thanks for all your comments and help you took to help me understand this very simple concept of limit.

Comment: @fleablood:Sorry to bother you but I still couldn't get why $2+h^2$ is a decreasing function.So while reading this article on limits it tells that we're really approximating the function a value at a particular instant say $n=\infty$ so they start at $0$ and continue upto $\infty$ which might not be a pratical option but still we could see that the sequence starts getting to 1.While I tried to look expanding $2+h^2$ at $x=0$ I'm getting values that start from $-\infty$ and extends to $0$.So that maybe correct that this...........

Comment: @fleablood:.....function is a decreasing function upto $x=0$ but afterwards the function again starts to increase from $x=0$ to $x=\infty$.So do we only look upto 0 or should we go upto $n=\infty$?If you say "we should only look upto $x=0$ it's sure that it's a decreasing function".If it's _not_ I'm not sure whether it's a decreasing function.Could you help me.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)}=L$$
implies and is implied by
Given any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ for all $|x-a|<\delta$.

This can be rephrased as follows:

The function $f(x)$ tends to $L$ as $x$ tends to $a$ if we can make $f(x)$ as close to $L$ as we wish by making $x$ sufficiently close to $a$.

So, what is being said here is when $f(x)\rightarrow L$ when $x\rightarrow0$ *it is not enough that that $f(x)$ gets closer to $L$ as $x$ gets closer to $a$*, it means that by making $x$ sufficiently close to $a$, you can make *$f(x)$ arbitrarily close to $L$*.

This is because, say $h=100$. Then, $2+h^2=10002$. Now, you bring $h$ closer to $0$ by making $h=10$. Then, $2+h^2=102$. It can always be said that now, $h$ is coming closer to $0$ (since $|102-0|<|10002-0|$), and $2+h^2$ is coming closer to $1,2,3.6,-12.3221,...$, any number $n$ such that $|10002-n|>|102-n|$. However, the limit is $2$ as only $2$ satisfies the criteria above.

In your example, no matter how close $h$ is to $0$, $|2+h^2 - 1|>1$.

The fact that $1$ is not the limit can be verified by the $\epsilon-\delta$ test, by taking any $\epsilon<1$.

Comment: Coincidently, the answer is similar to StackTD's comment.

Comment: :Could you mention what's $\epsilon$ and $\delta$?

Comment: @justin $\epsilon$ (epsilon) is any arbitrary positive number. Given $\epsilon$, we need to find a positive $\delta$(delta), such that the above holds. This is the definition of a limit.

Comment: :Could you explain a little bit more about why you say that "you can make _f(x) arbitrarily close to **L**_"

Comment: That is how a limit is defined. L is the limit if you can make f arbitrarily close to L by making x sufficiently close to a. By arbitrarily close I mean as close as I wish.

Comment: @Yeah that's very right from this article:(http://1drv.ms/1RvyMOk) (P.30).

Comment: Getting "arbitrarily close" means you can "get as close as you like" means for any positive value no matter how small (lets call that value $\epsilon$; we don't actually care what $\epsilon$ actually is.  The point is we can choose $\epsilon$ as small as we want.)  for any value no matter how small... we can get *closer* than that.  To only say "we get closer" in comparison is pathetically weak.  As I get taller I get closer in size to the size of ... the moon.  I never get *close* in size to the moon, but I get *closer* in size.  A gazzilion kg is closer than a gazzilion and 1 kg.

Comment: @fleablood:Could you help me with the term _closer_.Could you tell why we get closer in the size to size of the moon as we get taller.I think I'm confused with the term _closer_.

Comment: Maybe getting closer to the moon is a bad example.  I wanted an extreme example.   The moon is 2,159 miles in diameter.  6 feet 1 inch is closer to 2,159 miles than 5 feet 7 inches is.  "closer" means "the diference between them is less".  London is closer to the south pole than Liverpool is.  \$5.27 is closer to the national budget than \$5.26.  27 nonometers is closer to 257 billion lightyears than 26 nanometers.  etc.

Comment: @fleablood:Yeah you're really cool and helpful.I could see this from your comments that you go upto any _extreme_ level.That's very good.

Answer (score 1):

Simply observe that the function $f(h)=2+h^2$ is continous on the whole $\Bbb R$, hence in particular in any nhbd of $0$, thus
$$
\lim_{h\to0}f(h)=f(0)
$$
and clearly $f(0)=2$.